# Project stated with vue-cli 2 or 3

Tags: vuejs2, vue-cli, vue-cli-3

How can I see if a Vue project has been created with vue-cli 2 or vue-cli 3?

Currently I have the problem that I have to import Vue like that:

```
import Vue from  'vue/dist/vue.js'
```

instead of

```
import Vue from  'vue'
```

Someone asked me how I started the project and I can not remember if it was vue-cli 2 or 3

Comment: How about check "@vue/cli-service" version in package json for the very first commit?

Answer (score 0):

The Vue-CLI is the command line interface, not the package that you use in your application. To discover which version you've used, run this command  on the terminal:

```
$ vue --version
```

It will show something like below:

```sh
[youruser@youcomputer ~]$ vue --version
2.9.6
```

Comment: But this depends on the system right? My desktop uses the new version and my laptop has the old one. And how do I know which of my devices I used to create the project?

Comment: You don't know where did you started it? Well, there isn't a way to discover it. You could take a look at the File Properties, to see where it was created, and it may help you.